Extracting colored numbered balls and calculating the probability of their PRODUCT
Let's say I have an urn with B balls colored in C = C0, C1,..., CC-1 different colors. C > 1.
I start with a quantity Q = 1,
I extract (without replacement) E balls, one after the other. Depending on the color of the ball, I multiply Q by a coefficient. The coefficients are 0 for C0 and larger than 0 for all the other colors.
I would like to calculate the probability of all the possible final values of Q.
Example: if my urn contains five balls (one blacK with coefficient 0, two Red with coefficient 2 and two Green with coefficient 3) and I extract two of them, these probabilities are:

Q = 0 : 0.4
Q = 4 : 0.1
Q = 6 : 0.4
Q = 9 : 0.1

My numbers would be higher (many more balls and colors) and I can't easily handle this with brute force.
The coefficients could be rational and different colors could have coefficients that share factors. In the same problem I could have balls with coefficients 0.5, 2, 4, 8 and the final product could be 16, obtained in several different ways.
I could use the Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution to calculate the possibility of extracting all the possible combinations of balls colors but my instinct tells me it is possible to do this with generating functions.
I know I am onto something with this example where I forget momentarily about the blacK ball.
Let's say I have 4 balls (in parentheses their coefficient): RED (2), RED(2), GREEN (3), GREEN (3).
If I expand the following: $(x+2R)^2 • (x+3G)^2$
I got a lot of numbers I am interested in:
$36 G^2 R^2 + 36 G^2 R x + 9 G^2 x^2 + 24 G R^2 x + 24 G R x^2 + 6 G x^3 + 4 R^2 x^2 + 4 R x^3 + x^4$
There are coeffients like 4, 9 and 6 toward the end and these are the possible products I can have by drawing two balls... but I can't read out the number of ways I could exctract them.
There is a 36 that is the product of all four coefficients.
There is another 36 and this could be the 18 that I get with 3x3x2 ... taken twice because I can choose the Red(2) ball in two different ways.
Same goes for the 24: it is the 2x2x3 taken twice.
There are, in all, 9 terms, and it's surely not a coincidence that I need 9 terms to describe all possible products that I can get, according to the number E of balls that I extract:
0 balls extracted:

1 in one way ------------> x^4

1 ball extracted:

2 in two ways ---> 4 R x ^ 3  ---> I need to divide this by R
3 in two ways ---> 6 G x ^ 3  ---> I need to divide this by G

2 balls extracted:

4 in one way ---> 4 R^2 x^2 ---> I need to divide this by R^2
6 in four ways ---> 24 GR x^2 ---> I need to divide this by R•G
9 in one way ---> 9 G^2 x^2 ---> I need to divide this by G^2

...and so on....
I just need a sound way to go from all the coefficients to these numbers.
In another attempt I expand $(1 + 2 R x)^2 (1 + 3 G x)^2$ and I get something even better but with the same issues:
$36 G^2 R^2 x^4 + 36 G^2 R x^3 + 9 G^2 x^2 + 24 G R^2 x^3 + 24 G R x^2 + 6 G x + 4 R^2 x^2 + 4 R x + 1$
Still 9 terms of course. And I can say: if I exctract x balls, the number of ways I can get the value given by the literal coefficients in front of x when I substitute R=2 and G=3 is the numerical coefficient divided by that value.
Example: the second term is: $36 G^2 R x^3$
This tells me that by exctracting 3 balls (x=3) I can get the value G^2•R = 2x3x3 = 18 how many times? well, the coefficient divided by 18, that is, 36/18 = 2 ... that is correct!
I could already use this form but I am sure there is a more elegant way of expressing the generating function so that it is possible to better read the results.
Then, I need to take into account the black balls that multiplies everything by zero!
Thanks

Your example seems a bit simple for the general problem. Are the values on the balls allowed to share factors? If so, you may get the same product in several ways. If not, you're just asking (for instance) "what's the probability I pick three balls and get two reds and one green?". Either the product is important, in which case you have to think about factorisation, or it's not, in which case it's probably a distraction.

You didn't mention, by the way, whether the values assigned to the balls are integers; in any case, the above points still hold - if the same product can be achieved in multiple ways it's a problem.

Sorry my example was already so long...; yes, the balls can share factors and they can be rational numbers. I could have a ball with coefficient 8, two balls with coefficient 4 and four balls with coeff. 2. In this I case I could obtain a final product 16 by exctracting two balls: an 8 and a 2 or both the 4s.
